# Select top 1 of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, outer-join

Trying to select top record of a outer joined table

if there are no records in table B then null will be there

if there are multiple records then just the first one should be selected.

I built this query but I get error

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        A.Col1 , A.Col2, B.Col2, B.Col3
 FROM   
        A LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM B WHERE B.Col1=A.Col1) A ON B.Col1=A.Col1
```

***The multi-part identifier "B.Col1" could not be bound.***

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: You might want to use an `OUTER APPLY` instead.

Comment: The "B.Col1" that cannot be bound refers to the last part "B.Col1=A.Col1" because B is an alias of the table in the subquery (which you also aliased as A) and so is not visible outside the subquery.

You also refer to A.Col1 within the subquery which cannot be resolved either.
The subquery syntax is much harder to read & maintain. In general, use CTE syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one match, then use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT A.Col1 , A.Col2, B.Col2, B.Col3
FROM A OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP 1 *
     FROM B
     WHERE B.Col1 = A.Col1
    ) B;
```